How to find the average of two columns but if one value is null, then only show me the other value?
I have a table where I want to find the average value of column1 and column2, but in some cases there may be null values in either columns. In that case, I just want to be shown the value that is NOT null.
Example:



Column1
Column2




10
Null


9
15



So in this case I want to see:



Column3




10


12



I'm still a beginner so my knowledge is pretty limited, also I want to keep it as simple as possible. I'm using phpmyadmin if that makes any difference.
I've tried sum(table1+table2)/2 which results in null if one of the values is null.
I've also tried
SELECT 
   CASE 
     WHEN table2 IS null 
       THEN SUM(table1) 
     ELSE SUM(table1+table2)/2 
   END

but it just returns the average of rows where there isn't a null value (I only get back 12, not the 10 as well (refer to the above table))

You are near with the case expression.
There is no need for sum and you have not considered null for column1 .
Fixing those, the query would be :
SELECT 
   CASE 
     WHEN Column1 IS null THEN Column2 
     WHEN Column2 IS null THEN Column1 
     ELSE (Column1+Column2) / 2 
   END as column3
FROM myTable

See example

I did it differently in my answer to more easily extend to 3 or more columns, but this is a lot clearer if there are only 2.

@ysth since the OP is at the beginning stage of learning I thought to give a more simple to read answer.  I would choose your answer if it were more columns because it is shorter.

Thanks you both ErgestBasha and @ysth for your answers. This one is indeed more in my league at the moment. But I will definitely look more into the coalesce function. <3

select coalesce((column1 + column2) / 2.0, column1, column2)

I.e. if both column1 and column2 are non-null, return the average.
Otherwise return the non-null value (if any.)
If you want, you can add 0 as final argument to COALESCE, to get a 0 if both column1 and column2 are null.

Thank you for your simple explanation of the coalesce function, I'll definitely look more into it <3

This is even better

SUM is for summing values over multiple rows.  Here, you just want simple math and replacing nulls with 0 and counting non-nulls
select ( coalesce(Column1,0) + coalesce(Column2,0) ) /
    ( if(Column1 is null,0,1) + if(Column2 is null,0,1) )
    as Column3

